# RegEx Capture Group with PHP preg_match Not Returning Values

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to capture the text "Capture This" in $string below.

```
$string = "</th><td>Capture This</td>";
$pattern = "/<\/th>\r.*<td>(.*)<\/td>$/";

preg_match ($pattern, $string, $matches);

echo($matches);
```

However, that just returns "Array". I also tried printing $matches using print_r, but that gave me "Array ( )".

This pattern will only come up once, so I just need it to match one time. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong` You are trying to parse html with regex. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/278739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you require a CR character `\r`. Also you should make the search lazy inside the capturing group and use `print_r` to output the array. Like this:

```
$pattern = "/<\/th>.*<td>(.*?)<\/td>$/";
```

You can see it in action here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/djRJ0e

Note that it's recommended to parse html with a proper html parser rather than using regex.

Comment: Thank you very much, Marcus. Can you suggest an HTML parser that would be best for a simple situation like this? Would you recommend a specific library, or should I use PHP's DOM functions?

Comment: @bow-viper1 this might shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Comment: I would actually prefer to use PHP's DOM functions, but I just wasn't able to find any functions that can capture a single tag of many that don't have either an ID or class assigned to them. But, I will keep looking now that I understand that it's looked down upon to use regular expressions in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You need to drop the `\r` from your regex as there is no carriage return character in your input string.
2. Change `echo($matches)` to `print_r($matches)` or `var_dump($matches)`